# Show that $(a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4) \geq (a^3+b^3)^2$

Tags: inequality

Show that $(a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4) \geq (a^3+b^3)^2$

Can we go like this : $(a^2+b^2)=(a+b)^2-2ab \& (a^4+b^4) = (a^2+b^2)^2-2a^2b^2$  and right hand side of the inequality : $[(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)]^2$

Comment: Typically for two variable inequalities you want to first try algebra, then see if you can use the triangle inequality, Cauchy Schwartz, AM-GM inequality, etc.

If you don't come up with anything obvious, it sometimes makes sense to try the method of Lagrange multipliers. Although, you can run into some pretty messy algebra with Lagrange multipliers. With this specific example, you can try manipulating the inequality with algebra then using the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Apply [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) to the vectors $(a,b)$ and $(a^2,b^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying out and cancelling leaves $$a^2b^4+a^4b^2\ge2a^3b^3$$ which let's write as $${a^2b^4+a^4b^2\over2}\ge a^3b^3$$ which is true by the inequality of the arithmetic and geometric means.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any restrictions on $a,b$? RHS is $a^3+b^3 = (a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$. Clearly for all $|a|,|b|>1 \ \ a^2+b^2 >a^2+b^2 -ab$ and $ a^4+ b^4> a+b$

Answer (score 0):

$(a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4)-(a^3+b^3)^2$

$=(a^6+a^4b^2+a^2b^4+b^6)-(a^6+2a^3b^3+b^6)$

$=a^4b^2+a^2b^4-2a^3b^3$

$=a^2b^2(a^2+b^2-2ab)$

$=a^2b^2(a-b)^2$

$\geq 0$

$∴(a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4)\geq(a^3+b^3)^2$

**Q.E.D.**