# Proving that: $ (a^3+b^3)^2\le (a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4)$

Tags: inequality

This problem is from Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics:
Prove that $$ (a^3+b^3)^2\le (a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4)$$

It would be really great if somebody could come up with a solution to this problem.

Comment: Maybe it's AM/GM?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown You don't need that. See my answer.

Comment: @KennyLau That looks like AM/GM to me.

Comment: Cauchy scharwz inequality

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown you don't need the full strength of AM/GM. I only used the fact that a square is always non-negative (which I know is how you prove AM/GM for two variables).

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/312544/42969.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I do not look at the answers before mine and tried it myself with the most innovative thought I am able to have:  $(a^3+b^3)^2 = (a^2\cdot a + b^2\cdot b)^2 \le (a^4+b^4)(a^2+b^2)$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. As you can see how "beautiful" the CS inequality is....

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
& (a^3+b^3)^2 &\le& (a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4) \\
\iff& a^6 + 2a^3b^3 + b^6 &\le& a^6+a^2b^4+b^2a^4+b^6 \\
\iff& 2a^3b^3 &\le& a^2b^4+b^2a^4 \\
\iff& 2ab &\le& b^2+a^2 \\
\iff& 0 &\le& b^2-2ab+a^2 \\
\iff& 0 &\le& (b-a)^2 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks! This really helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

$$(a^3+b^3)^2 = a^6 + 2a^3b^3 + b^6$$

But we know that $$(X-Y)^2\ge 0\Longleftrightarrow X^2+Y^2 \ge 2XY$$

taking $X= a^3$ and  $Y=b^3$ we get 
$$2a^3b^3 \le a^2b^4+b^2a^4 $$
so 
$$(a^3+b^3)^2 = a^6 + 2a^3b^3 + b^6 \le a^6 + \color{red}{a^2b^4+b^2a^4 } + b^6  = (a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4) $$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\color{blue}{a^2b^2(a-b)^2} \geq 0 \\
\color{red}{a^6} +\color{blue}{a^4b^2+a^2 b^4} +\color{red}{b^6} \geq \color{red}{a^6} +\color{blue}{2 a^3b^3} +\color{red}{b^6} \\
(a^2+b^2)(a^4+b^4) \geq (a^3+b^3)^2.
\end{eqnarray*}